# Getting solana staking rewards for wallet

Tags: web3.js, staking

How to get all Solana staking rewards for a wallet?

I do not want iterate by epoch and get `getInflationReward`, I need only the sum of rewards. I want receive all rewards in one call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can find the instruction that delegated the stake account, and you never merged other stakes into it, you can simply take the difference in the balance at delegation and now.